# Can't add Sql Compact 4.0 as Datasource on RDLC

Tags: datasource, rdlc, vb.net-2010

i want to add on a `report (*.rldc)` a `DataSource` that is an `Sql Compact 4.0`, but it doesn't give me the option to add it, but i can add on Server Explorer an Sql Compact 4.0 connection.

What do i need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataTable / DataSet to Bind Records from you SQL CE to your Local report.

Just Click Add New item then choose DataSet and select you sqlce database on your server explorer.

This may help you to start of:

[Building Reports from Object Collection using ReportViewer](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/mahesh/building-reports-from-object-collection-using-reportviewer/)

[ReportViewer](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=510160)

Regards

Comment: Thanks so much for the info, but it doesn't show the "SQL Compact 4.0" option when im adding a new dataset, also draggin the connection from Server Explorer it tells my Designer is not compatible with Sql Compact 4.0

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 needs a patch to get support for editing SQL CE 4.0 databases.  you can get it through Web PI.