# Report Viewer doesn't show any data after publish

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Hello I'm using C# 2010 and sql server compact edition 3.5 to build my database, and I use report wizard to generate a report from my database, but unfortunately after I published the app, my report viewer doesn't show anything even I have inserted a new record. Here is my code to simply show data on report viewer :

```
this.jadwalkuliahTableAdapter.Fill(this.Dataset.jadwalkuliah);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Note : report viewer shows data from my database while debugging process.

Comment: Does it show the report header, but no data? Have you checked (sql trace) to see whether the database is being queried?

Comment: yes of course. but how do I know whether the data has been successfully queried? Would you show me how?

Comment: Is it Local Report(rdlc) or server report(rdl)?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing ReportDataSource:

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt = this.inputValuesTableAdapter.GetData();     

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt); 

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Check this site below:

[how can I load datatable as ReportDataSource? SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004307/how-can-i-load-datatable-as-reportdatasource)

[Building Reports from a DataSet using ReportViewer c-sharp corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx)

[Creating Dataset Dynamically in c# and passing to Report Viewer.. asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1681823/4948182.aspx/1?Re%20Creating%20Dataset%20Dynamically%20in%20c%20and%20passing%20to%20Report%20Viewer%20)

Best Regards

Comment: I wonder to know why this is not happen when I use sql server (not the ce version)?

Comment: there is no problem in your datasources..make sure that your dataset/datatable has its data..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425551/cant-add-sql-compact-4-0-as-datasource-on-rdlc

Comment: I have try your code above, but maybe you would like to see the result after i publish the app   [link](http://db.tt/jStF4R5D)